# Backbone render return undefined in the View

Tags: backbone.js

I am learning backbone and I seems to be having problem with my render method below. The render is always returning undefined when  I run it. Please can anyone help out with this.

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults : {
                status: 'true' , 
                description : 'Nothing'
            },
            toggleStatus: function() {

                if (this.get('status') === "completed")
                    this.set({
                        'status': 'completed'
                    });
                else
                    this.set({
                        'status': 'incompleted'
                    });
            }

        });

 // Simple View
        var simpleView = Backbone.View.extend({

            events: {
                'change input': 'toggleStatus'

            },

            initialize: function() {
                this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
            },

            toggleStatus: function() {
                this.model.toggleStatus();
            },

            template : _.template('<h3 class="<%= status %>">' +
                                  '<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +
                                  ' <%= description %></h3>'),
            render: function() {
                    console.log('render was called');
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
              // return this;

            }

        });
  var todonew =  new Todo(); 
  var newView = new simpleView({
            model: todonew
        });
```

Comment: render doesn't have to return something, is a function to print your result, what is the real problem?

Comment: I ran the newView.render() in chrome dev tools but the result was undefined. I was expecting the element with the result to the appended to the screen.

Comment: Besides the fact that `return this;` is commented out?

Comment: Well I tried return this and I received Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this  from the browser hence my comment.

Comment: You haven't specified an 'el' property so Backbone will create a detached <div> and render your view in it.  That's why it's not appearing on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably put brackets in the `if` statement of your template, that might cause trouble in some browsers.  Change this

```
'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +
```

to this

```
'<% if(status === "complete") {print("checked")} %>/>' +
```

Then there are at least three different ways to render the content to your page.  You need to give the view a DOM element which it can append its content to. Otherwise, it renders it's content into an empty `<div>` that is floating around in memory.  You are using jQuery, which makes it easy to select a DOM element.  I am going to use the `$('body').html()` to replace the entire page html, modify your selector according to what you need.

Option 1:  Uncomment `return this` in your render function, and modify this code at the end

```
var newView = new simpleView({
  model: todonew
});
$('body').html(newView.render().el);


$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

to this

```
$('body').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Option 2: Send in the element you want to add the content to when you create the view

```
  var newView = new simpleView({
    model: todonew,
    el: $('body') //or whatever selector you want
  });
```

Option 3: change this line in your render function

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

to this

```
$('body').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Again, this replaces the HTML for your whole page, use a different selector, or use `.append()` or another method instead of `.html()` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your `el`, this is the problem of your script when return error on `this`.
 try this for example:

```
var newView = new simpleView({
     model: todonew,
     el: $("#somediv") //put here a div or the element where you want to put your template
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I write:

```
$('#foo').append(bar.render().el);
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
```

To correct this, I added `return this;` in my `render:function(){}`.

```
  render: function() {
        // something else
        return this; // add this line
    }
```

Reference: [Backbone.js Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render)

> A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable chained calls.